# How can I count the results in Gnip's Powertrack API?

Tags: api, gnip

I am looking for a URL to count the results retrieved using Powertrack API. Something similar to what I find using Search API:

https://search.gnip.com/accounts/ACCOUNT_NAME/search/LABEL/counts.json

I've been looking at Gnip's docs but I have found nothing that allows me to count the results.

I tried using other URLs (stream.gnip.com, and using search.gnip.com with 'powertrack' instead of 'search'). I can't paste more than 1 link so I can't show the complete URLs here, sorry.

I also looked at Historical PowerTrack API reference, and I can't find anything there related to this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only products that support a counts endpoint are the [30 Day](http://support.gnip.com/apis/search_api/) and [Full Archive Search](http://support.gnip.com/apis/search_full_archive_api/) APIs.

Because PowerTrack is a streaming API and supports 10's of thousands of concurrent rules, your best bet would be to store the data into a database or document storage system (NoSQL) that would allow for filtered queries to extract the counts you need.

Historical PowerTrack could technically allow you to determine a count for a specific query, just based on the total number of activities returned, but to execute an HPT job for the sole purpose of getting a count would not be cost-effective.

Answer (score 0):

Like Steven suggested you better store it in a (NoSQL) database and perform your own aggregations.

Gnip does provide a [Usage API](http://support.gnip.com/apis/usage_api.html) which will give you the total volume per period per source.